# PBIX File Vs Editing in Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi

Is there a difference between looking at the Power BI Desktop File (.PBIX extension) and looking at the report created when you go to Power BI Report Server and click on "Edit in Power BI Desktop"?

Will everything be exactly the same or would it be better to just look at the .PBIX file if I want to see exactly how the report was created?

I am unable to test this myself at this time.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the file that has been uploaded in the Power BI (PBI) Service, you can be certain that this your live file that is currently being used in production.

When you open a .PBIX file on computer using the PBI Desktop, it might be the same file as the file downloaded from PBI Service, but there's no guarantee that no changes have been made to the file.

So if you want to know the current live file looks like, always download the .PBIX file from PBI Service.